# Anyway to only copy part of the file name into excel with macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I've saw a few post related to this question but the answer provided couldn't help me at all. For example my file name is "SPC_PLTB_450B_05092017_25°C_CW",how am I going to **only copy the date** in the file name and **paste it into my main workbook** using macros ? My macros will find the next empty cell in Column C and paste the date of the filename in it.

[image: What my main workbook looks like]
This is the macros I have now. Where can I insert the required code ? Thank you in advance.
    Sub trial()

```
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim fn As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'this is for the excel to add one more worksheet for the raw data
Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
Dim Ret

'this whole part is for importing the raw data files into excel
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Lkl Files (*.lkl), *.lkl")

    If Ret <> False Then
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "SPC_PLTB_450B_12092107_25°C_CW"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
        .TextFileThousandsSeparator = "."
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

        End With
    End If


    Sheets(2).Activate

    'this is to search for the next empty cell and put the date
    Dim FirstCell As String
        Dim i As Integer
            FirstCell = "C19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop
            ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    'this is to filter the raw data into the desired value
    ws.Activate
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    'change the value of Criteria1 between "" into the desired value for filtering
    ws.Range("$A$9:$P$417").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        "1"

    Range("F31:F401").Select
    Selection.Copy



    Sheets(2).Activate


    'this is for the raw data to be copied into each worksheet

            FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

   Sheets(3).Activate
    FirstCell = "C19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop
            ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ws.Activate

    Range("D31:D401").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy


    Sheets(3).Activate
            FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

        Sheets(4).Activate
    FirstCell = "C19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop
            ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ws.Activate

    Range("G31:G401").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy



    Sheets(4).Activate
    FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

With ActiveWorkbook
    .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, considering ".Name = "SPC_PLTB_450B_12092107_25°C_CW" is hard-coded, you might as well just hard-code the date along with it. Is this your code?

Comment: `Split(fileName, "_")(3)` will give you the date part.

Comment: I wouldn't want to hard-code it because the date of the file isn't fix, the date varies that's why hard coding it is out of the list. Yes that is the code that is suppose to work along with whatever I'm doing. Just in case you need it.
@TimWilliams does that code make me hard-code it in the end as well ? Sorry because I'm still very new to VBA so I'm trying to learn as much as possible. Just exposed to VBA for a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this UDF to extract the 8 digit date part from your file name. I have edited the code to return date in date format.

```
   Function datepart(filename As Variant) As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String
    For i = 1 To Len(filename)
        If Mid(filename, i, 8) Like "########" Then
            s = Mid(filename, i, 8)
            datepart = DateSerial(Right(s, 4), Mid(s, 3, 2), Left(s, 2))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

for writing it in the next empty cell in column A you can write something like this

```
 ActiveCell = datepart(ret)
```

Comment: for the UDF part, which is it that i have to put my own codes ? Or do i just literally copy the whole thing and paste it in my macros only? I'm really really new to VBA, sorry..

Comment: You can paste the User defined function anywhere after/before your sub module.Put it after the last End Sub after which you can call that function anywhere in your module.so in your case replace this line ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy") with ActiveCell =datepart(ActiveWorkbook.Name) i.e. you can calling UDF in active cell.

Comment: i tried doing what you said, i replaced everything with "ActiveCell =datepart(ActiveWorkbook.Name)" and put the function after the end sub only, somehow it turns out empty. Ia it possible that I have to edit something from the code you written above ? Do i put the filename replacing your code "filename" ?

Comment: filename is just an argument for the function it can be anything.            Press Ctrl+G inside VBA editor and in the immediate window write               ?datepart (ActiveWorkbook.Name) and see if you are getting any output.

Comment: i typed in as you said, but there was no response.. what am I supposed to expect ? I put the "?" sign and without the "?" sign but both didn't work. I dont see any changes in the worksheet as well..

Comment: Immediate windows shows you code result inside that window so when you type ?activeworkbook.name you should see the workbook name below that line.I just tried your code and I'm getting the value in activecell.

Comment: Yes, the code i did was fine if it was using the date for each day. The problem is that my supervisor wants it to be the date in the file and not the date for today. If it were to be the date for today then my code works fine sadly it's the other way round.

Comment: Try replacing ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy") with 
ActiveCell.Formula = datepart(ws.QueryTables(1).Name)

Comment: We're getting close I think, there is a date now but not the right date. Like, if I were to run the program, the date is 12th of September, but the file that i chose is 5th of September.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155799/discussion-between-imran-malek-and-fong).

Answer (score 1):

You may have this UDF on a standard module and then use it whenever you have to pull the date from the file string.

```
Function GetFileDate(ByVal fName As String) As Date
Dim RE As Object, Matches As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RE
   .Global = False
   .Pattern = "\d{8}"
End With
If RE.test(fName) Then
   Set Matches = RE.Execute(fName)
   GetFileDate = Format(Matches(0), "00-00-0000")
End If
End Function
```

And then in your code, use this function by passing the string which contains the date part in it.

```
ActiveCell.Value = GetFileDate(ws.QueryTables(1).Name)
```

Comment: I can barely understand for the UDF part, I'm still new to VBA so is it possible where you help me adding it into my vba to show me an example? It's like you showing me the answer but I don't even know how to implement it. Really appreciate and sorry for the inconvenience.. @sktneer

Comment: I have edited the answer, please paste this UDF in your code module in the end and use it in your code as suggested.

Comment: Tried it out and I got a date now.. but sadly, the date is different from the filename. It shows 9th of September no matter what file I pick, and the date of the files aren't 9th of September..

Comment: 1) What is the file name? 2) What date do you expect? 3) What's date format as per your regional settings? VBA understands only American date format i.e. mm\dd\yyyy. Please answer the three queries I asked so that I can fix it.

Comment: The file name varies all the time. An example of the filename is "SPC_PLTB_450B_05092017_25°C_CW". The date part will always change as it is according to the date the data is produced. I expect the date to be the same with the one on the filename. Date format for the one i'm trying to do is dd-mm-yyyy.